# Mvc: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables-editor

Please help me why i am Getting This Error. Here i wana to show my table in JqData Table

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="myTable">
    <thead> <tr> <td>EmpId</td> </tr></thead>
@foreach (var ee in Model.GetEmployeeFromHybridge) {
    <tbody><tr> <td>@ee.Emp_Id</td></tr> </tbody>
        }        
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
        $('#myTable').DataTable(

        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to put your table in `body` tag.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mvc - its a jQuery issue. And the error means that `dataTables.js` is not loaded, or that you loading a copy of `jquery.js` after it (possibly due to loading it in the _Layout.cshtml_ file as well.